# email sender authentication with Postfix

Tags: postfix-mta, spf, dkim

I have setup PostFix for receiving emails only.

I want to authenticate the received emails against their sender email addresses by using SPF or DKIM.

Is there a good java plugin available for this? or do i need to write my own in java (other preferences C, C ++) ,please reply with relevant references.

Thanks in advance

Ashish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I followed is as:

I attached the DKIM and SenderID milters available from Postfix add-ons list with my Postfix e-mail server.

Since these milters can be configured to add e-mail headers in the received mails about their results, so I wrote a custom mail-filter using jilter api (java mail filter api), parsed the mail headers and hence I was able to determine and act about the authentication results of SPF and SenderID according to my custom logic.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Postfix is not one of the mail servers that suppose SPF natively, but there are some extensions and patches for this, which can be found at http://www.openspf.org/Implementations.

While a java library is available for SPF, I'm not aware of any plugins or patches that are currently using it.